# How to print the table(pointer) contents in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm new to Lua, and I need to serialize and print a variable in Lua, following is my code.

```
local function serialise_obj(data)
    if type(data) == "function" or type(data) == "userdata"
            or type(data) == "cdata"
            or type(data) == "table" then
        return tostring(data)
    end

    return data
end

print(serialise_obj(sample_variable))
```

The following prints the pointer to the table (`table: 0x7fefd84e3398`). How can I make it print the content of the table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to explicitly print it such as `for key,value in pairs(data) do print(key, value) ...` another approach would be to overload the behavior of `tostring` to handle tables.

Answer (score 0):

you need cickle:

```lua
local fucntion serialize_obj(data)
  local retval = ""
  if type(data) == "table" then
    for key, val in pairs(data) do
      -- XXX need do somthing with key?
      retval .. serialize_obj(val) -- concatenate to retval
    end
  else
    -- some other logic
  end

  return retval
end
```

If `data` is `array` with strings and/or numbers, then you can use `table.concat`